# Pushing to heroku failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am a collaborator on a Heroku app programmed in Rails I am getting this error when trying to push to the staging environment. I am only a collaborator on the staging environment of the application and not the production repo. When I try `git push heroku master` I get the following error:

```
Hugos-MacBook-Air:app_name hugo$ git push heroku master
To git@heroku.com:app_name-test.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:app_name-test.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I don't understand the information I am getting when enter the git help command. I have setup the remote heroku repo and I have logged in too. I have also added my ssh keys to heroku.

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:app_name-test.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:app_name-test.git (push)
```

Above are the heroku repos. Also this is the repo that I have associated with the heroku app. `git@github.com:app_name/app_name.git` I haven't pushed to the github repo yet so is that my problem?

Can anyone be of assistance? I'd really appreciate it thanks.

Comment: What is the result of `git pull` ? Could you push after running this command ? This message usually came when you have difference in the git remote repo and in your git repo (commit that are on the remote but not on your local), if you do not care about the code on the remote repo you can just force the push by running `git push -f heroku master`

Comment: Currently I am getting a 502 error, not sure why. But earlier when I checked, everything was up to date. I'd rather not have to force a push though. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Those responses are gone. Everything up to date.

Comment: What if you run `git fetch heroku && git merge heroku/master` is everthing up to date too ?

Comment: thanks for the help that worked. My colleague was testing something on the test site and hadn't pushed those changes to github. Write an answer if you want.

Comment: Writed ! Just to not leave the question unanswered ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `git fetch heroku && git merge heroku/master` to be sure your local repo is up to date with your remote repo on heroku.